# Java regex performance metrics?

Tags: java, regex

Given the following code, how can I get metrics for a regular expression?  Does Matcher and Pattern give any visibility into the performance of a match/find or would I have to calculate this manually?

Something like this:

```
String text = "...some really big string of containing a pattern to match...";
        Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("<the pattern to match>",
                Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
        if (m.find()) {
          // ????? How long did find() take to match the pattern ?????
        }
```

Comment: How would you measure time for any other method?

Comment: Set a time value = now then find the detla between that and the time to execute the method + now. How would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, if there are no methods to access performance metrics, then there is no visibility.  Java doesn't have any concept of hiding special methods for some purpose or another that are secretly accessible through some special trick.

If you're wanting performance metrics you'll just have to use `System.currentTimeMillis()` (or if you're needing more resolution, `System.nanoTime()`) and note the difference in time between starting and ending your methods.